# Maximal proper subfields and the behavior of the norm

Tags: field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field

This is a more general version of my previous question ([Yet another question on finite fields](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1526685/yet-another-question-on-finite-fields)), which has yet to attract any comments (nevermind answers). It occurred to me that I might be getting bogged down in the specifics. So, here goes:

---

Suppose I have two distinct maximal proper subfields $K$ and $L$ of a finite field $F$.

Let $\alpha \in K^*$. When does an element of $\{\alpha N_{F/K}(x) : x \in L^*\}$ have order less than $\# K^*$?

Answer (score 1):

If $K$ and $L$ are distinct maximal proper subfields of a finite field $F$, then there must be a prime $p$, two primes $q_1\ne q_2$, and a positive integer $r$ such that $\#F^* = p^{q_1q_2r}-1$, $\#K^* = p^{q_1r}-1$, and $\#L^* = p^{q_2r}-1$; it's also true that $K\cap L$ is a proper subfield of both, with $\#(K\cap L)^*=p^r-1$. (All these groups are cyclic.)

There are $\#F^*/\#L^* = (p^{q_1q_2r}-1)/(p^{q_2r}-1)$ distinct translates of $L^*$, which together partition all of $F^*$; in particular, all elements of $K^*$ are in some translate. Each time a translate intersects $K^*$, it does so in $\#(K\cap L)^*=p^r-1$ elements.

Therefore there are a total of $\#K^*/\#(K\cap L)^*=(p^{q_1r}-1)/(p^r-1)$ translates of $L^*$ that intersect $K^*$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I made a mistake in the original question, I meant to ask about the translates of the image of $L^*$ under the norm $N_{F/K}$. I've edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: I don't really understand the new question. The image of $N_{F/K}$ lies in $K$, right? So any translate by $\alpha\notin K$ can't possibly intersect $K$.

Comment: Dang, that was another mistake. I'm requiring $\alpha \in K^*$, though I know I had $\alpha \in F \backslash L$ written initially.

Basically, I want to know when an element of $\{\alpha N_{F/K}(x) : x \in L^*\}$ has order less than $\# K^*$.

Comment: If you're running through all $\alpha\in K^*$, then every element of $K^*$ will be in the same number of translates.... Anyway, sorry, but I'm done. If you edit the original question to (finally) ask exactly what you mean to ask, perhaps someone else will offer to help.

Comment: Look, if you're getting frustrated then you could simply refrain from posting any more on this thread; the attitude is unnecessary.

Comment: Yeah, fair enough. I apologize.